# Lists active network ports and protocols over time

Tags: linux, networking, sysadmin

Is there a linux server utility that can list the network ports and protocols that have been active over a given period of time?

For example, I'd like to know which ports and protocols were active at least once last week. The answer would be something like: TCP/80, TCP/443, UDP/5678...

Comment: What do you mean by "active"? A process was listening on one of those ports? There was an incoming connection on one of those ports? A process connected to that port on a remote server? Something else?

Comment: I mean that incoming connections have occurred.

Answer (score 3):

You can install and activate `auditd`. Add there rules in audit config:

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S connect -F key=CONNECT
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S bind -F key=BIND
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S socket -F key=SOCKET
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S listen -F key=LISTEN
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S shutdown -F key=SHUTDOWN
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S close -F key=CLOSE
```

and you will have in audit logs you can monitor socket related system calls.

If you want to find now old information (and do not have `audit`) I do not think you will find relevant information in linux.

Comment: Thank you. That utility seems to be a good fit for monitoring the socket activity of the server. However, the log it produces is dense. How can I extract the desired information? Digging a little bit deeper, I have found https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-auditd-monitor-network-connections-alex-maestretti/ along with https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LinuxSupport/IDSNetConnectionLogger. Still, I can't make my way out of it.

Comment: @Numid, you can filter by using `key` value directly from `audit`. And then filter by port, IP, etc

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to tracing within hosts' network stack is tracing traffic on the wire.

Take a packet capture of the interfaces in question. Either on that host, or somewhere in the path.

Various tools exist to parse that, definitely TCP and UDP information and possibly some insights into applications. Wireshark is free, but its far from the only packet analysis tool.

Comment: I am afraid that sniffers would provide too much info. I am looking for a summary of the activity. However, maybe there are Wireshark filters for that purpose. If so, let me know!

Comment: Wireshark and packet capture tools in general are inherently dealing with data on the wire. You can query the capture for only TCP and UDP ports. The methods have different disadvantages. Auditing the kernel socket system calls may miss non socket uses like ICMP, or user space network stacks.  Packet capture is storage intensive and may contain sensitive information.